# Android Javascript form submit working on 2.1-update1, but not 2.2 and above

Tags: android

I have an activity where I use a webview with an android buttons below it. I load a web html form in the webview. Instead of having a submit button in the html form I have placed the following simple javascript function in the page:

`function submitFrm() { 
    document.listupdate.submit();
}`

In my activity an android button triggers the javascript and the form submits. Works like a charm in Android 2.1-update1, but it will not work on 2.2 or above. Like I said this does already work on Android 2.1-update1. Can anyone bring me up to speed as to why, and what changes I need to implement?

```
upDtListingtBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){ 
  @Override  
  public void onClick(View v) {  
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.listinginfowebview);  
    **webView.loadUrl("javascript:submitFrm()");**  
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ListingInfoActivity.this, "", "Updating...");  
    new Thread() {  
    public void run() {  
    try{  
    sleep(2000);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
    }  
    progressDialog.dismiss();  
    }  
    }.start();  
}});
```

And yes javascript is enabled - it works in 2.1update1!

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

The rest of the code block, as you can see just runs a dummy progressDailog.

Answer (score 0):

Much to my  embarrassment for having my head in the sand, and not keeping myself informed;
it would appear that the long-standing Javascript - Document Object Method - Form Method of binding:

`document.form.submit();`

is not supported in the Android webview after 2.1-update1 in preference of supporting the jquery method.

`$("form").submit();`

So after downloading and placing the:

`<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/xyz/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>`

file reference in the head of my html document;
I simply changed the syntax to the jquery method:

`function submitFrm() { $("listupdate").submit(); }`

The form is now submitting in Android 2.2 and above. No changes were necessary in the Java Code!